# AHK build "central" of keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I would like to have a universal shortcut, either on the computer as a whole or just in some limited programs (like for example only when chrome is active).

(PS. I use AHK language here, so ^ is ctrl ! is alt + is shift).

I would like to press a shortcut, for example hit ^{Space} and then write someting, like "email" and press enter to open outlook.

I can also hit

> ^{Space}
>
> ch
>
> {Enter}

and launch chrome.

This have been done by the program **Launchy**. What I would like to do, however, is to make this more flexible.

For example, I'm not satisfied with the keyboard shortcuts in my program MyLifeOrganized (MLO). I have to press +1 or +2 to add a note or tag on a todo item. Instead, I want to have this happen:

> ^{Space}
>
> type "nn"
>
> get to the note.

Since the part of getting to the note already has a keyboard shortcut, this should be able to be done via AHK

- ^Space::
- Prompt message box

  - if I write "nn"

    - Send +1
  - if I write "nn"

    - Send +2
  - etc...

How can I make this "mapping" work?

Answer (score 2):

A program called SlickRun does this out of the box.

If you want to use Autohotkey, the solution easy to construct using an input box.

```
^Space::
inputVar :=""
InputBox, inputVar, Launch,,,200,110
If (inputVar = "ch")
{
Run, chrome.exe
}
Else If (inputVar = "email")
{
Run, outlook.exe
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You could configure the Everything utility to open with your hotkey and then limit its scope to a "file list" that you can define and edit in a gui (for example by adding your start menu folder and removing unnecessary links).